# Ionic Active Segment Not Highlighted when Multiple ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem in using Ionic segments. I use dynamic values (ngFor) for the segment and its contents. The problem is, the selected active segment is not highlighted.

I have a simple array like this in my component, order-menu.ts:

```
public myCategories = 
  [{
    catName: "Chicken",
  }, 
  {
    catName: "Beef",
  }];

public mySelCategory: string = "Chicken";
```

I want to display this segments in ionic app.

This is my template, order-menu.html:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="mySelCategory">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let category of myCategories" value="{{category.catName}}">
        {{category.catName}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div [ngSwitch]="mySelCategory">
    <div *ngFor="let category of myCategories">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="category.catName">
            <ion-item>
                {{category.catName}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to show the data correctly using segment, however it **does not highlight the active segment.**

[image: Active Segment not highlighted]

I noticed that if I do not include this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="mySelCategory">
    <div *ngFor="let category of myCategories">
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="category.catName">
            <ion-item>
                {{category.catName}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

, the active segment is shown correctly.

[image: Active segment ok if no multiple ngFor]

Can anybody help to troubleshoot this? Or any workaround? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I think the segment's border (the line below the selected active segment) is outside of its container. Thus when we have an item below it, the border is covered by that container.

I added this line in my order-menu.scss to check the border of active segment:

```
  .segment-button.segment-activated{
    border: 2px dashed black !important;
  }
```

Now you can see that the bottom border is not visible.

[image]

As a workaround, I added a class to my segment HTML and scss:

```
<ion-segment class="menuSegments" [(ngModel)]="mySelCategory">

  .menuSegments{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

Which then results to this:

[image]

I then remove the `.segment-button.segment-activated` class from my scss to get the default settings from ionic for the bottom border.

[image]

I am currently using `"ionic-angular": "^3.9.2"`.

I think ionic team has solved this in ionic 4. This problem does not occur in ionic 4 (by today, 20 Nov 2018).

Answer (score 0):

> do not use ngModel. instead try (ionChange) and then you can provide in value a default
>   value which selects that segment by default.

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="categoryChanged($event)" value="chicken">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let category of myCategories" value="{{category.catName}}">
        {{category.catName}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

> you can capture the value of changed segment this way

```
categoryChanged(value) {
console.log('segment is', value['detail']['value']);
}
```

> **Update**: Also the above snippet is for ionic v4